Final Predictions accuracy of my ML Binary Classification Model is horrible
I am competing in a Kaggle competiton (https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/playground-series-s4e8) where we have to predict whether a mushroom is poisonous or not based on the data provided.
The issue I am facing is that my models perform well inside the training and validation sets just fine (around 98-99% accuracy) but they fall apart when I actually submit the final predictions for the competition.
The best accuracy I got until now using the Random forest model was 52% and the rest of my submissions had substantially worse performances. Since the models are performing well inside the notebooks and data with labels,
I assumed that the issue is with the way I am handling data in general because I did not implement techniques like feature engineering and I am not sure if the way I converted categorical data to numeric data works fine or not.
And as mentioned before, I am using the Random Forest Model and/or XGBoost model and these two models are quite well known to be a lot less prone to overfitting than other models.
I also ran multiple iterations of multiple models to find the models with the best parameters (as evident from the code below) so that makes the problem of overfitting less likely.
Here is the code for my data handling:
def dataType(array_like):
    return array_like.dtype.name
types = []
for i in range(df_shape[1]):
    category = dataType(df_train[df_train.columns.values[i]])
    if category == 'object':
        types.append(1)
    else:
        types.append(0)
print(len(types))
print(types)
for t in range(len(types)):
    if types[t] == 1:
        column = df_train.columns.values[t]
        encoder = LabelEncoder()
        df_train[column] = encoder.fit_transform(df_train[column])
print(df_train.head())
features_to_scale = ['cap-diameter', 'stem-height', 'stem-width']

scaler = StandardScaler()
df_train[features_to_scale] = scaler.fit_transform(df_train[features_to_scale])
# df_train = df_train.replace('NaN', 0)
X = df_train[['id', 'cap-diameter', 'cap-shape', 'cap-surface', 'cap-color', 'does-bruise-or-bleed', 'gill-attachment', 'gill-spacing', 'gill-color', 'stem-height', 'stem-width', 'stem-root', 'stem-surface', 'stem-color', 'veil-type', 'veil-color', 'has-ring', 'ring-type', 'spore-print-color', 'habitat', 'season']].to_numpy()
Y = df_train['class']
knn_imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=3)
imputed_X = knn_imputer.fit_transform(X)
# X[np.isnan(X)] = 0
# Y[np.isnan(Y)] = 1
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    imputed_X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

print(np.isnan(X).sum())
print(np.isnan(imputed_X).sum())

My code for XGBoost implementation and finding the model with the best hyperparameters:
 def objective(trial):
          param = {
         'max_depth': trial.suggest_int('max_depth', 2, 10),
         'learning_rate': trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', 0.01, 10.0, log=True),
         'n_estimators': trial.suggest_int('n_estimators', 100, 1000),
         'subsample': trial.suggest_float('subsample', 0.5, 1.0),
         'colsample_bytree': trial.suggest_float('colsample_bytree', 0.5, 1.0),
         'gamma': trial.suggest_float('gamma', 0, 5),
         'min_child_weight': trial.suggest_int('min_child_weight', 1, 10),
         'reg_alpha': trial.suggest_float('reg_alpha', 0, 1),
         'reg_lambda': trial.suggest_float('reg_lambda', 1, 5)
     }

     # Initialize the model with the suggested parameters
     model = xgb.XGBClassifier(use_label_encoder=False, eval_metric='logloss', **param)

     # Train the model
     model.fit(X_train, y_train)

     # Predict on the test set
     y_pred = model.predict(X_test)


     accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

     return accuracy
 study = optuna.create_study(direction='maximize')

 study.optimize(objective, n_trials=75)

 best_params = study.best_params

 best_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(use_label_encoder=False, eval_metric='logloss', **best_params)

 best_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

 y_pred = best_model.predict(X_test)

 accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
 print(accuracy)

My code for Random Forest implementation and finding the model with the best hyperparameters:
params = (
    (2, 10, 42),
    (5, 20, 0),
    (10, 30, 123),
    (15, 40, 1),
    (20, 50, 7),
    (2, 15, 99),
    (5, 25, 56),
    (10, 35, 78),
    (15, 45, 100),
    (20, 60, 202),
    (3, 12, 8),
    (6, 18, 15),
    (12, 28, 30),
    (18, 38, 60),
    (25, 50, 90),
    (8, 20, 45),
    (14, 32, 67)
)

model = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=35, min_samples_split=10, random_state=78)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions_train = model.predict(X_train)
predictions_test = model.predict(X_test)
accuracy_train = accuracy_score(y_train, predictions_train)
accuracy_test = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions_test)
print(accuracy_train)
print(accuracy_test)
random_forest_model = model

for min_samples_split, max_depth, random_state in params:
    model = RandomForestClassifier(min_samples_split=min_samples_split, max_depth=max_depth, random_state=random_state)
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    predictions_train = model.predict(X_train)
    predictions_test = model.predict(X_test)
    random_forest_models.append(model)
    accuracy_train = accuracy_score(y_train, predictions_train)
    accuracy_test = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions_test)
    random_forest_accuracies_train.append(accuracy_train)
    random_forest_accuracies_test.append(accuracy_test)
    print("Model trained")

print(random_forest_accuracies_train)
print(random_forest_accuracies_test)

I then save the model with the highest accuracy (with the least overfitting) and save it in my kaggle notebook.

There does not have to be anything wrong in the code to have bad performance, just that the feature distribution shift and your model does not work anymore, so this is not a programming problem but a machine learning one (generalization), which is off-topic in Stack Overflow.

Also note that for new data points, you have to normalize them the same way as the training set, I don't know if you are doing that because it does not seem to be covered in this code, but it would be the only programming mistake that could explain your results.

Suggest simplifying the question by eg removing the XGB example and giving a minimal example (eg reduce params, get rid of comments). And you should also show your inference code (where you make a bad prediction), otherwise this Q is likely to get closed.

One of the most common reasons for getting garbage predictions, especially if the predictions are all the same, is forgetting to scale the input for inference. That is, apply the fitted StandardScaler from your preprocessing.
The best way to avoid this pitfall, and a few others, is to use pipelines. It's a bit more complex for you because you only want to scale some columns. So, for example:
from sklearn.pipelines import make_pipeline

# Must split dataset before scaling.
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.2, stratify=y, random_state=42
)

# Use pipelines!
ctx = ColumnTransformer(
        remainder='passthrough',
        transformers=[
            ('scaler', StandardScaler(), features_to_scale),
        ])
model = RandomForestClassifier(min_samples_split=10, random_state=78)
pipe = make_pipeline(ctx, model)

# Fit model etc etc.
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = pipe.predict(X_test)

This has the side benefit of encouraging you not to scale the data before splitting it (another common pitfall).
There are a few other things you should do:

Consider splitting test into val and test sets. The purpose of val is exploring algorithms, hyperparameters, etc. And the purpose of test is finally checking the performance of your selected model. Read this carefully.
Consider not only looking at accuracy, but also at recall and precision, and at the confusion matrix. Consider other accuracy measures like Matthews correlation coefficient, or looking at the ROC-AUC curve.
If there is any class imbalance, you should stratify the train-test split.
Once you know your optimal hyperparameters, don't forget to fit a model using all of your data! (The model trained on X_train was only to help optimize the hyperparameters and estimate performance.)

